# 2 rows created in database when create a new post or page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to Wordpress and I'm trying to figure out how Wordpress works.

I notice that when I create a new post or page, in ***wp_posts*** table, 2 new rows created, can anyone explain to me why this happens.
Also when I update a post or a page in the dashboard, a new row is created in ***wp_posts*** table, I thought the old one should be updated instead of creating new one.
Thank you!

Comment: For any post, there is atuo save and revision feature. It  stores a record of each saved draft or published update.

Answer (score 0):

When you create post or page so insert entry in `wp_post` table . and also add featured image so insert data into `wp_post` table with parent id of post and when update post so insert new record in the `wp_post` table because insert record with post status inherit and post type revision.